# Why insert and update query name variable is undefined in ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am working on ColdFusion9 and MySQL 5.0. I am not sure why the query name variables get undefined in the insert and update queries, even if I have declared those variables just before the query. Here is the sample code.

```
<cfset variables.test_update = QueryNew('')>
<cfset variables.res = ''>
<cfquery name="variables.test_update" datasource="dsnTest" result="variables.res">
    INSERT INTO test(
        name
        , rank
    )VALUES(
        'test'
        ,23
    )
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#variables.res#">
<cfdump var="#variables.test_update#">
```

Here the result attribute value is available, but for the query name variable, it is throwing the undefined error, "Element TEST_UPDATE is undefined in VARIABLES."

I know that, the insert, update and delete queries do not return any result set through the query name attribute. But, I am not sure, why does that query name variable get undefined after the query execution?

Please help.

Comment: When you specify a result atribute, my understanding is that it replaces returning any information into the query_name attribute, so you'll need to use variables.res where you'd normally use query_name

Comment: @barnyr, I removed the "variables" scope from the query_name, but it does not fix the error.

Comment: @barnyr - you are wrong. The result is actually meta info about the query, not the rows itself. The docs say exactly what is covered, but it is different info then the rows itself.

Comment: @RaymondCamden thanks for letting me know. I'll have a play with that as it's been a while since i've looked at what's in result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ColdFusion populates `variables.test_update` with whatever is returned from the DB driver, which in this case is [nothing].

And CF considers a null variable to be undefined. Always has.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what Adam says, if you wanted to return the new ID for the new record (if your table is setup to handle this), you could change it as follows:

```
INSERT INTO test(
    name
    , rank
)VALUES(
    'test'
    ,23
);
Select LAST_INSERT_ID() as newid;
```

if you dumped "variables.test_update", you would see its now not empty, returning one row, for the column "newid".

Comment: You do not need to do this. If you use the result attribute, the new ID is returned in that struct for you. Even better, it is cross platform (db platform).

Comment: @cf_phil, I am not trying to get the ID of the newly inserted row, rather I am trying to know why that query name variable gets undefined.

Comment: I know - I was just trying to highlight that although your variable was undefined because your query returned nothing, it WOULD be defined if you requested data within your cfquery (for example, by added a follow-on query inside the cfquery tag - IF you needed it).